# jQuery pass var between event

Tags: jquery, events, mouseevent

I try to understand how I can pass a DOM betweenjQuery events.

For example, I created a simple tooltip plugin and it appends on `mouseenter` a div and I would like to remove on `mouleave` the same appended div. However if I have multiple elements which are hovered I can't select the right element to remove.

Here a simple example code:

```
    $(this).on('mouseenter', function() {

        $('<div class="'+options.class.split('.').join('')+'"></div>').appendTo('body').addClass(options.hoverClass.split('.').join(''));
        $tooltip = $(document).find(options.class).last();

    }).on('mouseleave', function() {

        $tooltip.first().removeClass(options.hoverClass.split('.').join(''));
        setTimeout(function() {
            $tooltip.first().remove(); // remove the right DOM appended for the element hovered
        },400);

    });
```

original code: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Lw4behcu/1/

**EDIT**: Working fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Lw4behcu/2/

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `data()` method to store relevant tooltip:

```
$(this).on('mouseenter', function () {
    var $tooltip = $('<div class="' + options.class.split('.').join('') + '"></div>').appendTo('body').addClass(options.hoverClass.split('.').join(''));
    $(this).data('tooltip', $tooltip);


}).on('mouseleave', function () {
    var $tooltip = $(this).data('tooltip').removeClass(options.hoverClass.split('.').join(''));
    setTimeout(function () {
        $tooltip.remove(); // remove the right DOM appended for the element hovered
    }, 400);

});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't think to that! here a working example http://fiddle.jshell.net/Lw4behcu/2/